# Google Script e.values error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, gs-installable-triggers

I have looked at other similar posts and got some help with setting up trigger correctly but still have an error.
I have tried to automate sending a pdf doc to be emailed in response to a form submission in google apps. I used a script shared on web to get started and have fixed some deprecated terms.
I created a document template with `keyItems` embedded as placeholders and I created a form to capture data. The spreadsheet associated with the form is capturing data as planned. I edited the script associated with the spreadsheet to hopefully do the work required on submission of the form. The trigger looks correctly set up to run `on form submit` `from the spreadsheet`. My question is about the error I get repeatedly regarding the `e.values` being undefined. I assumed that I would be labelling these as `e.values[0]` and onwards when I declared the variables - i.e. they would be based on their order in the array drawn from the spreadsheet fields. Sorry to be long winded. If i place dummy content in the variables it works and sends the pdf so the actual mechanism works ok but my `e.values` are not working.

Here is my script 
// Certificate of Completion

// Get template from Google Docs and name it

```
var docTemplate = "1V_PqCBZ9vWmmIELp47X12iNtdwRCqHyOyey6VPL0o0Q";
var docName = "CertificateOfCompletion";
```

//When form submitted get info from form and set as variables

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var name = e.values[2];
  var email = e.values[3];
  var date = e.values[4];
```

//make temporary working copy of template doc for the submitter

```
 var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName+' for '+name).getId();
```

//open the temporary doc

```
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
```

// tell script to go into the doc

```
var copyBody = copyDoc.getBody();
```

//replace placeholders in the doc with data from a submitted form

```
copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', date);
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

//create PDf

```
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
```

//send email to recipient

```
var subject = "Certificate";
var body = "Congratulations!" + name + " Here is your certificate of completion " ;
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
```

//delete temporary document

```
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using named values instead.

Heres an example

```
var handling = Number(e.namedValues["Call Handling"]);
var security = Number(e.namedValues["Security"]);
var agentName = String(e.namedValues["Agent Name"]);
```

These are questions in a form I have. The bit after the e.namedValues["text here"]); , replace text here with whatever your column is called in form responses, this will be the question name.

I'm not sure why e.values[0] onwards isn't working for you as it works for me.

My script is in the spreadsheet, with an onFormSubmit trigger installed via the menu.

Also bear in mind, to test your script, you must sumbit a form, hitting the play button won't work as there is no event to pass to your function.